# Find and update all the keys value in a nested JSON Arrays and Objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, nested

I have below nested JSON data of Arrays and Objects

I need to update the all the keys value in string from english to spanish in javascript or NodeJS or AngularJS

```
    {
      "firstrootkey" : [ //Array of 6 objects 
      {  //1st object
        "key1" : "valueinstring",
        "key2" : randomnumbers
      },..... ],
      "secondrootkey" : { //having 7 objects 
        "One" : [ { //each object having array of n objects 
          "name" : "valueinstring",
          "id" : randomnumbers
        }, ......],
        "two two" : [ { // array of m objects
          "keya" : "valueinstring",
          "keyb" : randomnumbers
        },.......],
      .
      .
      .

      },
      "third root key" : { //having n objects 
        "sdfdsfsfs" : [ { //each object having array of n objects
          "keyc" : "valueinstring",
          "keyhuh" : 858556
          "hgjhgj" : 6789
        },.... ],
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        }
    }
```

I tried to somany methods but none of them working...
one of the approach

```
   for (var rootKey in jsonEnglish) {
    var rootValue = jsonEnglish[rootKey];
      if (rootValue.isArray) { // function iterate Array objects         
        //loop each array
          // if every array is object -- function iterate object 
            // find value in object 
              //if value not array and object 
                 // then pass value to translator 
                  //and update the value with translated value
              //else if its object
                  //
```

Give some directions to approach

Comment: In what way is your approach not working? It sounds promising to me.

Comment: @Shan418, Please add a Fiddle/Plnkr of your code.

Comment: It seems like you do not know the depth of your objects. Maybe some [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) would help you.

Comment: Yes i don't know the JSON Structure and Depth. It varies by URIs. I will try recursion also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, start by validating your JSON here http://jsonlint.com/

Then in javascript you can access json and use it with XMLHttpRequest()

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "yourdata.json";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var json_array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);                    
                parseJson(json_array);
        }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    json_data += "<p>Variable Access through array structure: " + json_array.firstrootkey[0].key1+ "</p>";
    json_data += "<p>Access Array inside array item: " + json_array.secondrootkey[0].one[0].name + "</p>";

    document.getElementById("display_json").innerHTML = json_data;
```

Also, there is a syntax error on line 7. Also, to test your code you a need a working web server. I prefer appserv.

Here is some JSON that is right and verified on JSONlint.com

```
{
    "firstrootkey": [{
    "firstName": "Shane",
    "lastName": "Burton",
    "id": [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    ],
    "credits": "24"
}],
"secondrootkey": [{
    "One": [{
        "firstName": "Shane",
        "lastName": "Burton",
        "id": [
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
        ],
        "credits": "24"
    }]
}]
}
```

Second JSON OBJECT Each set of brackets represents one row in your database/list

Since you're using a foreach loop I would make it one object for simplicity sake.

```
{
"foreachloopobject": [{
    "firstrootkey": [{
        "firstName": "Shane",
        "lastName": "Burton",
        "id": [
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
        ],
        "credits": "24"
    }],
    "secondrootkey": [{
        "One": [{
            "firstName": "Shane",
            "lastName": "Burton",
            "id": [
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
            ],
            "credits": "24"
        }]
    }],
    "firstrootkey": [{
        "firstName": "Shane",
        "lastName": "Burton",
        "id": [
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
        ],
        "credits": "24"
    }],
    "secondrootkey": [{
        "One": [{
            "firstName": "Shane",
            "lastName": "Burton",
            "id": [
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
            ],
            "credits": "24"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: Dots in my JSON Data represents the Occurrence of either array or objects

Comment: I can't use any hardcoded value in the code like json_array.secondrootkey[0].one[0].name.

Comment: It's not the dots, it's the fact that you use a { instead of [. Line 7 has no dots? Just make sure to test it in jsonlint. It will tell you if the syntax is correct. From what your showing me that Json is not going to work. I'll edit my answer to have some json.

Comment: Where are you pulling the data from? Can you verify it with JSONlint.com? Example http://buttraxx.com/json_get_data.php Here I pull data from a mysql server and create a json object. It doesn't have to be hard coded, you just need to get the object.